# Load external font using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fonts

I have a multi lingual site using AngularJS
I want to load a font using a .woff file, but i don't want to load it every time the site loads, only if it's loaded with the font's specific language. 
I mean something like that:

```
function init(lang){
  if(lang == 'eng')
  // Load font here 
}
```

I can easily use ng-class to take care of applying the font style in my css, so that is not the issue, I worry about loading redundant fonts on other languages and harm my sites loading time.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load external font with javascript and jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282151/load-external-font-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: @LajosArpad This is not exactly what I need, looking for a more angular friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

> SCSS will help you to make it.
>      [Also refer it its same question I found.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26001431/8002731)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Durant';
src: url('../fonts/DurantBold.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: bold;
}
```